# if isset statement with javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

În php I would use this to see if a variable is set and then use that value, otherwise make it a zero:

```
    $pic_action = isset($_POST['pic_action']) ? $_POST['pic_action'] : 0;
```

But what is the equivalent in javascript?

I want to check if an element exists in the document, and then if it does, add it to the variable, otherwise add some other value to it, here is what I have so far:

```
    var areaOption = document.getElementById("element");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById("element")` will return `null` if the element doesn't exist -- and something not-`null` if it exists.

Which means you should be able to do something like this :

```
var areaOption = document.getElementById("element");
if (areaOption) {
    // element exists
} else {
    // element doesn't exist
}
```

(You could also compare `areaOption` with `null`, instead of just checking if it's non-falsy)

Comment: This is hardly replicating the `isset()` function in PHP.

Comment: or use `typeof (variable) == 'undefined'` to check.

Answer (score 2):

```
var areaOption = document.getElementById("element") || some_other_variable;
```

Answer (score 2):

`isset()` checks whether the variable is defined and not null. Javascript scoping rules being different from PHP, checking whether a variable is defined is harder. You can, on the other hand, determine if it is null:

```
if (areaOption === null) areaOption = ... ;
```

Then, there's the classic Javascript idiom using the lazy evaluation of `||`:

```
areaOption = areaOption || ... ;
```

The latter does not check for the variable being null, merely if it's equivalent to `false`, which means the right-hand part will be evaluated even if the value is defined (and is `0` or `''`), which may be unsafe if you rely on the types being valid.

Answer (score 2):

The more verbose approach:

```
var c = document.getElementById("a") ? document.getElementById("a") : "b";
```

Or the shorter version:

```
var c = document.getElementById("a") || "b";
```

If you want to access a property, say `innerHTML`, on a given element, if the element exists; the first example can be re-written, like so:

```
var c = document.getElementById("a") ?
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML /*element exists: return innerHTML*/ :
    "" /*element does not exist: return nothing*/;
```

... Without the comments:

```
var c = document.getElementById("a") ?
        document.getElementById("a").innerHTML :
        "";
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're trying to accomplish is something like this:

```
var dummy = null;
var areaOption = (dummy = document.getElementById("element")) ? dummy.value : 0;
```